# Create stroke inkcanvas from inkpoints

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, stroke, inkcanvas

I want to create a stroke from a list of inkpoints , my problem is in the second parameter of the method, the Matrix 3x2.
this code I have an exception:

```
            List<InkPoint> inkpoints = new List<InkPoint>();
            InkStrokeBuilder ink = new InkStrokeBuilder();
            System.Numerics.Matrix3x2 matr= new System.Numerics.Matrix3x2();
            InkStroke stroke = ink.CreateStrokeFromInkPoints(inkpoints,matr);
            inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStroke(stroke);
```

the exception:

$exception  {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}  System.ArgumentException

Comment: Not sure why you're specifying a zero matrix. It would collapse all your points into a singularity. You probably want the identity matrix: `System.Numerics.Matrix3x2.Identity`.

Comment: thanks a lot , you're right!!!